# Divide a website into three separate elements

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to design a new idea of mine but I'm having issues positioning things on the actual page.

My idea is to have a menu section to the very left, a feed in the middle and another menu to the left, however, I cant seem to get the positioning right.

I want the two menus to share the same settings and to not be scrollable, but the middle feed segment to be scrollable as it's going to be updated with content through a database.

Any ideas?

```js
state = "Minimized";

function controlCenter() {

  if (state == "Minimized") {
    document.getElementById("centerExpandable").style.display = "block";
    state = "Expanded";
    console.log("Expanded");

  } else if (state == "Expanded") {
    document.getElementById("centerExpandable").style.display = "none"
    state = "Minimized";
    console.log("Minimized")
  } else {
    console.log("Invalid Value " + state);
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.right {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20%;
  height: 80%;
}

.center {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
}

.centerExpandable {
  background-color: lightBlue;
  display: none;
}

.left {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20%;
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="right">
  <h1>Im The right panel</h1>
</div>
<div class="center" onClick="controlCenter()">
  <h1>Im The center panel</h1>
  <div id="centerExpandable" class="notes">
    <p>Im expandable content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="left">
  <h1>Tasks Only</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: Image of wanted design]

Comment: Can you show us what you've worked with?

Comment: As @JerdineSabio said to provide some code that you have worked on so that we can able to find a solution. Most probably you can use CSS grid to make this or you can go with any other CSS framework like bootstrap or materialize CSS

Comment: @JerdineSabio I added the code that I wrote so far to my post, and thank you for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use flexbox like that:

```css
#container
{
  display:flex;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
} 

#left, #right
{
  background-color:green;
  width:100px;

}


#center
{
  flex:1;
  background-color:blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
  </div>
  <div id="center">
  </div>
  <div id="right">
  
  </div>
</div>
```